# Install Windows XP alongside Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-8, installation, multi-boot

I have a 64-bit CPU, but my computer has 32-bit Windows 8 installed. Could I somehow *trickily* install another Windows XP 64-bit alongside that?

I want to do this because I almost never use the Windows 8 apps, and mainly use this machine for Java development. So I would like to run a lightweight OS implementation. Additionally, with the 64-bit version of Windows XP I would be able to take advantage of my 64-bit CPU.

So how do I do it? :)

Comment: There is... but if you have Windows 8, most likely you won't have driver support. Knowing the computer's model would go a long way.
I never tried it but it should be the same as installing a new Windows on a new partition and then restoring the Windows 8 bootloader.

Comment: It'd help a lot to know the model number to find drivers, yep. However, it's also important to realize that XP is nearing its end-of-life, and it may not feel as lightweight as it seems.

Comment: if you are going to stick with windows, don't do xp but go with win7. XP is dead this spring (no more security updates etc...) and using it as a primary OS would be dicey. Use Windows 7 or go with linux as primary and virtualize win8 inside... add more memory too

Comment: I think the crux of this question is will user01's current 32-bit bootloader allow for booting of a 64-bit OS?  Also, if the system is GPT, I'm not sure XP 64 supports it?  The [first question in this FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx) suggests no booting for GPT drives in XP 64?

Comment: [Windows 8 vs XP](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/02/operating-system-smackdown-windows-8.html): 8 turned out to be faster.

Comment: If you're using windows 8 then your CPU may be new, which windows XP can't take advantage of all its new feature, for example the AVX/AVX2 instruction set. WinXP x64 is the first 64-bit windows OS, so it sucks and has lots of bugs. You should use windows 8 x64 instead, it's not any heavier than XP and in fact will be faster because of more superior SuperFetch, fastboot and many newer software/hareware features

Comment: Besides, PCs shipped with windows 8 are often using UEFI with GPT partitioning scheme, which windows XP can't boot from

Comment: I do want to upgrade to **64 bit** Windows 8 from my current **32 bit** windows8 but there is no easier path to upgrade without losing all my data on system. As I know, a full format is required. but I would be really excited if I can do that..:)

Answer (score 1):

Installing Windows XP onto another partition will break the Windows 8 bootloader, but you can still make it work.
Make a partition for XP and install XP there. Once the installation is completed, the PC will now only boot to XP because XP's bootloader can't see Win8. To fix this, boot from a Recovery medium or your Windows 8 install disk, choose your language, then select "Repair computer" (or so). Open the commandline and execute:

> bootrec /fixmbr
>
> bootrec /fixboot

This will restore Windows 8's bootloader and add XP to it.
You should now be able to boot to both OSs.

Edit: I think this only applies to MBR-disks. If you have a GPT disk (normally that isn't the case for Windows-first installations), then I don't know if it'll work.

Comment: I'd advise against doing this though; I would not install XP anymore.
Since you want to develop Java on a lightweight system, i would recommend installing e.g. elementary OS Luna or any other Linux that is to your liking as a dualboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows 8 Pro or Ent installed you can use Hyper-V and run XP in a VM, that would be the smart thing to do.

Comment: "*I want to do this because I almost never use the Windows 8 apps & majorly use this machine for java development. So I would like to run a lightweight OS implementation.*"

Comment: You are aware windows XP is going to be dead in less than six months?

Comment: "Generally I would always recommend to only have ONE partition these days. Going down the route of making multiple partitions is like having multiple wives/girlfriends/lovers… it’s all fun and games for a while but ends with disaster.""

- Andreas H.

Comment: Well, if we were supposed to use only one partition then we wouldn't even use partition table - why do that if we can format entire hard drive to, let's say, NTFS? Why are we switching from BIOSes to UEFI if it requires additional boot partition? And yes, I am aware that XP is obsolete, but OP asked this question because he wants a lightweight OS. Running two OSes simultaneously is an opposite of lightweight. Even if it's a good idea in general, it doesn't make sense in this case. He's not desperate to run XP whatever it takes, he just wants a less demanding OS.